# Example of a function that converges to 0 pointwise but integral is 3/2?

Tags: integration, analysis, functions, continuity

Give an example of a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$, $f_n : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that converges to zero pointwise, and such that the integral of each function within the given domain is $\frac32$?

Comment: the integral of what function?

Answer (score 2):

Noting that $\int_0^a x(a-x) \; dx = a^3/6$, let
$$ f_n(x) = \cases{ 9 n^3 x (1/n - x) & for $ 0 \le x \le 1/n$\cr
                    0 & otherwise\cr} $$

Comment: That should do it.  +1

Answer (score 1):

$$ f_n(x) = \cases{ 3nx & for $ 0<x<\frac{1}{2n}$\cr
                    3-3nx & for $\frac{1}{2n} \leq x < \frac{1}{n}$ \cr
                    0 & otherwise\cr} $$

Comment: The sequence $f_n(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1/n$

Comment: I didn't see continuous, I will edit

Comment: @Dr.MV edited for continuity